# Calling cgo macro function

Tags: go, cgo

I have a cgo program:

```
package main

//#define sum(a,b) (a)+(b)
import "C"

func main() {
        print(C.sum(1,2))
}
```

It should be very straight forward and print 3. But compilation failed:

```
could not determine kind of name for C.sum
```

As limited documentation I found with cgo and after some test, cgo works with macro constants, but how can I get it work with macro functions/arguments?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241836/c-macro-definitions-in-cgo (doesn't look like you can use 'function' macros in go)

Answer (score 5):

Simple, you just need a wrapper:

```
//#define SUM(a,b) (a)+(b)
//int sum(int a, int b) {
//  return SUM(a,b);
//}
import "C"

func main() {
    print(C.sum(1, 2))
}
```